# EE 3.4.5 - white screen when using relationship field

Tags: relationships, ee3, white-screen-of-death

We're using EE 3.4.5, whenever we add a relationship field to an entry and view it on the front end, we get a white screen.  Removing the relationship field shows the page as normal.  Is this a bug or has anyone found a fix for it?

Comment: Go to config.php file and and change $config['debug'] = 2. And refresh the white screen page. You will definitely find actual errors.

Comment: We've found the issue, we had an IF check to see if the relationship field was blank or not.  Removing the IF tags fixes it